# Is there a way to open a bookmark in the sidebar in Firefox without clicking on the bookmark in the bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks, sidebar

I currently use Remember The Milk and have a bookmark for my task list set to open in the sidebar (as described [here](http://lifehacker.com/5002003/keep-your-to+do-list-in-the-sidebar)).  I don't typically have my bookmarks toolbar displayed in Firefox (same with the menu toolbar, to save space), so anytime I want to open my task list, I have to right click in the tiny space above the navigation toolbar, click on "Bookmarks Toolbar", and then click the bookmark.  Is there an easier way to accomplish this?  A keyboard shortcut would be ideal.  Is it possible to do something with AutoHotKey to make this possible?

Comment: I found a good solution for this problem. [Please take a look at this post.](http://superuser.com/questions/232925/how-can-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-bookmark-on-firefox/312698#312698)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ctrl-B** will open your bookmarks in the sidebar. You can then tab into the bookmarks list and select Remember The Milk. Probably still more steps than you want but might help a little bit.

Comment: And of course, I have the Delicious extension installed, so this opens my Delicious bookmarks.  I'll dig around and see if I can't make this method work somehow, maybe by changing the keyboard shortcut for Delicious.  Definitely sounds like it might be better than nothing.

Comment: It turns out the Delicious extension specifies a different shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + S) to open the bookmarks sidebar.  From there, I can type in "RTM", tab, space, enter, and it opens the bookmark in the sidebar.  Certainly better than fooling with the mouse!  Now I'll just see if I can put together an AutoHotKey script to do all that for me.

Answer (score 1):

These Firefox extensions might just be what you're after:

- [SpeedDial](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/4810)
- [SiteLauncher](http://www.donesmart.com/sitelauncher/)
- [samFind](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9866)

Also, there's a [Mozilla Forum topic](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1218135&start=0) asking something very similar.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Sadly, none of these extensions open a bookmark in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of **Awesome Bar** in Firefox.

If you remember some words of the bookmark you are looking for, just type them in the URL place. It should suggest you the bookmark you want in the drop down list, then just click or use keyboard up/down+enter to select the bookmark you want.

Comment: This opens the bookmark in the main browser window, not in the sidebar.