# How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to open a bookmark on FireFox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks, sidebar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to open a bookmark in the sidebar in Firefox without clicking on the bookmark in the bookmarks toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/30874/is-there-a-way-to-open-a-bookmark-in-the-sidebar-in-firefox-without-clicking-on-t)

For example, I would like to open my Google calendar (set to open on FireFox sidebar) by Ctrl-Cmd-C.
Thanks.

Comment: You could try AutoHotKey. http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: interesting software! but I'm using a MacBook.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not a duplicate - Opening the bookmarks toolbar and opening a single bookmark with a keyboard shortcut are very different things.

Answer (score 8):

No need of a Firefox add on. Just right click any bookmarks select properties and add keyword there.  Now you can open your favourite site by just entering the keyword in the address bar. This post will help

https://web.archive.org/web/20121010000427/http://browserland.com/how-to/how-to-assign-keywords-to-bookmarks-in-firefox/

But with this solution you cannot use CTRL,cmd etc..,  I hope this is the closest solution to this problem!!!

Comment: I tried that. It is convenient!  However, it doesn't open my page on the sidebar (though I set it to do so)..  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AhLeung If you like my solution, please mark it as accepted or vote up If you want more plz ping me.  I will try to come with more solution.  Thanks!!!

Comment: This is not a keyboard shortcut as asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a pretty neat solution for this issue. All you need is [Keyconfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) (detailed Infos [in this thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)) which allows you to (re)bind Firefox Shortcuts.

Follow those easy steps:

1. Add your Bookmark
2. Edit your Bookmark and add an keyword in the keyword field
3. Close Firefox
4. Depending on your OS open the file `prefs.js`:

   - OSX: `/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/RANDOMVALUE.default/prefs.js`
   - Windows: `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profile_name\prefs.js`
   - Linux: `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js`
5. Add: `user_pref("keyconfig.main.xxx_key__Keyword 1", "!][][][if(window.loadURI) loadURI(getShortcutOrURI('**YOUR_BOOKMARKLET_KEYWORD**',{}));");`
6. Open Firefox and go to Extras > Edit Shortcuts (make sure to select 'Keyconfig' in the selectbox above, if you don't, you would edit the shortcuts just for a particular site)
7. Assign the shortcut of your choice and save.
8. Restart. You're done.

Comment: I know that some would point out that instead of editing the prefs.js directly you better should add an user.js in the mentioned directory. But when I customized the user.js, I had the problem that after every restart, the shortcut needed to be reassigned. So I ended up editing the prefs.js directly (which shouldn't be a problem anyway).

Comment: sounds interessting, but sadly does not work anymore on ffx33 and keyconfig 0.3.1. The "Keyword 1" does not appear in "Extras > Key settings"

Comment: KeyConfig no longer exists for more recent versions of Firefox.  A lot of its functionality was taken over by the Firefox built-in `Manage Extension Shortcuts` (from the gear-menu of `about:addons`) but that is limited to addon shortcuts as the name implies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this add-on might help you: [iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863/)

Comment: I just tried the add-on, but it cannot record my action (opening a bookmark).  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at all-in-one sidebar?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/all-in-one-sidebar/

I have not used this in years but according to the description, it has embeddable webpages in the sidebar and configurable shortcuts.

> - open Bookmarks, History, Downloads, Add-ons, Page Info, Page Source, and Error Console in the sidebar
> - fully customizable toolbar at the left side of the browser
> - quickly show/hide the sidebar and the toolbar with a thin switch
> - toggle the sidebar by clicking or just by mouse movements
> - all panels are optimized for displaying in the sidebar (including slim lists)
> - place the sidebar on the left or on the right side of the browser
> - configure the behavior at the browser start or in fullscreen mode
> - MultiPanel for opening webpages in the sidebar, amongst other features
> - configurable shortcuts and additional buttons
> - third-party add-ons are supported
> - can be extensively customized

However I don't know if you can assign a shortcut to open the sidebar without a CMD/Ctrl/ etc.